# Percentage price change

Tags: product, price

i want in details product page display with  $_product->getPrice()   and $_product->getSpecialPrice(), also the percentage by which the price has been changed, how i can display this percentage  in page?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$origPrice = $_product->getPrice();
$finalPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();

$percentage = ($origPrice - $finalPrice) * 100 / $origPrice;
```

This covers both cases: when you have a special price and when you have a catalog rule that discounts your product price.
All you need to do is print the `$percentage` variable.
Also, do a verification if `$origPrice` is not zero, and format the variable value as you want.